# How to find out from where (x) integral of a function (from that point to infinety) starts to be lesser than some eps?

Tags: c++, c, math

So we have some function like `(pow(e,(-a*x)))/(sqrt(x))` where `a`, `e` are const floats. we have some float eps=pow (10,(-4)). We need to find out starting from which `x` integral of that function from that x to infinety is less than eps? We can not use  functions for special default integration function just standart math like operators. point is to achive max evaluetion speed.

Comment: Yep - it looks like homework from school - but beleve me it is not=(

Comment: int eps=10^(-4) looks a bit strange...

Comment: You seem to be quite misguided. `int` variables cannot represent decimal numbers, and `^` is not exponentiation in C. You **must** use functions from `math.h` just to exponentiate. `math.h` does not provide anything remotely close to a "solve integral" function.

Comment: Just to be certain, you need the least `x`, or will any `x` satisfying the requirements do?

Comment: Please clarify the following: "... functions for special default integration function just standart math like operators". In addition, do you need a solution for the functions you mentioned or a wider class of functions?

Comment: Functions of the class you specified (products of exponentials and fractional power series) tend to have integrals in known forms (i.e. the result is another function) and either big textbooks with tables of integral functions or - gasp, cheating ;-) - wolfram alpha will tell you the result. Leaving it as an exercise to the reader to translate the question into something wolfram alpha will grok.

Comment: +1 for the tag "continuous integration", it makes me smile

Comment: Is `e` the irrational constant _e_, or just a normal number?

Comment: e - is 10 dights aprox for real e=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, no one seems to understand the question. The question is: given some function f, find the smallest x such that Integral _ x ^ +inf f(x) < eps. That's the question. So basically we try x = 0, then x = 0.1 then x = 0.2 ... until the integral, for all intents and purposes, vanishes.

For example, given the bell curve for IQ of programmers on SO, at what IQ is the cumulative intelligence of programmers with higher IQ vanishingly small? If we pick x = 100 we know at least half the programmers will have a higher IQ than 100, if we pick 120, how many are left? What about 200? If we have 10,000 programmers here and eps = 1/10000 we're basically asking what IQ the top 0.01% of SO contributors have.

The question is: what is the most efficient way to find this number, given that nothing is known about f other than that is decreases fast enough that its the integral from x to infinity approaches zero as x approaches infinity?

The general answer is: you must start with a guess of some kind. If the result is too big, double your guess, and keep going until you satisfy the requirement. Then, go back to the last value you had (which didn't) and do a binary chop to find the smallest x satisfying the requirement.

To make a good guess is hard. One way is to use a Chebychev approximation of the function, integrate it analytically, solve the problem with the resulting polynomial, and use the solution as your starting guess. The assumption is that all functions look like polynomials off sufficiently high order in any given range.

Comment: this was answered quite handily above.  Why don't you think Josephine's answer was correct?

Answer (score 6):

If you perform the u-substitution u=sqrt(x), your integral will become 2 * integral e^(-au^2) du.  With one more substitution you can reduce it to a standard normal.  Once you have it in standard normal form, this reduces to calculating erf(x).  The substitutions can be done abstractly for any a, and the results hardcoded for simplicity and speed.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate this integral you need calculate [Error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). If you use gcc you can find `erf(...)` function in math.h, but it doesn't take params to get exact precise. But you can evaluate Error function's value by youself just using Taylor's series. With given eps it possible to calc the exact number of terms of the series.